# подскажите как можно быстро заменить текст с счетчиком +1

Tags: текст

есть текст в виде

> {"apartment":1,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.1"]},{"apartment":2,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.2"]},{"apartment":3,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.3"]},{"apartment":5,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.5"]},{"apartment":7,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.7"]},{"apartment":8,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.8"]},{"apartment":9,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.9"]},{"apartment":10,"forward_numbers":["sip:10.33.101.10"]}

нужно заменить 10.33.101.1 на 10.33.200.21 и так далее  след 10.33.101.2 на 10.33.200.22

Comment: На каком языке? Или всё-равно? )

Comment: Если замен немного, то проще и быстрее руками в Notepad++ "Find and Replace".

Comment: много файлов и они большие

Comment: точнее замена 500 раз в 60 файлах  единственное нашёл что в нодпаде можно все эти файлы открыть и менять разово но ручками через замену так наверно будет проще

Comment: Если есть возможность поставить nodejs, можно скриптик накатать в несколько строк и можно будет его дергать из командной строки. Если ОС винда, можно заморочиться и просто js код сделать.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Answer (score 0):

> **Предложу решение на javaScript**

Если сможете себе поставить [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en), то вот такой короткий скрипт может менять данные

```
import fs from 'fs';
// Читаем файл и преобразуем его
const file = JSON.parse(`[ ${fs.readFileSync('./jsons/tst.json', 'utf8')} ]`);

const a = 200; // Заменяемое значение
const b = 20; // Добавляемое

const newFile = file.map(rec => {
  const ip = rec.forward_numbers[0].split('.'); // Разбираем IP
  ip[2] = a;
  ip[3] = Number(ip[3]) + b;
  rec.forward_numbers[0] = ip.join('.'); // Собираем строку обратно
  return rec;
})
// Записываем данные в файл
fs.writeFileSync('./jsons/tstModyfy.json', JSON.stringify(newFile).slice(1, -1));
```

Ниже тот же скрипт, но для наглядности работы(без чтения и записи в файл)

```js
const file = [
  { "apartment": 1, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.1"] },
  { "apartment": 2, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.2"] },
  { "apartment": 3, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.3"] },
  { "apartment": 5, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.5"] },
  { "apartment": 7, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.7"] },
  { "apartment": 8, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.8"] },
  { "apartment": 9, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.9"] },
  { "apartment": 10, "forward_numbers": ["sip:10.33.101.10"] }
];

const a = 200;
const b = 20;

const newFile = file.map(rec => {
  const ip = rec.forward_numbers[0].split('.');
  ip[2] = a;
  ip[3] = Number(ip[3]) + b;
  rec.forward_numbers[0] = ip.join('.');
  return rec;
})

console.log(newFile)
```